# Delegate method for when adding pins to a MapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

This probably another silly question - but is there an MKMapViewDelegate method that can be called when pins are added to a MapView? I have tried the ones that seem obvious to me - such as didAddAnnotationView but either I have not set up my classes properly or it's not the right one - if there is one!

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: i did read the documentation - and there was nothing that immediately suggested itself as what I was after so I tried it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any such delegate method. `mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` is close, but it will probably only be called when those pins are actually about to appear on screen.